# Do i need to release parameter in asynchronous function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, function-parameter

I've googled a lot for this, but get no clue for it.

First of all, i'm not using ARC.

let's say i am calling a asynchronous function, and passing a pointer A to it, initialially i thought, okay, let's pass a autoreleased pointer A to it, the async function will release A after it finished its operation. but seems it won't work.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"someurl"]] autorelease];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Then there's a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error coming in, if i remove the autorelease, then it goes fine.

anyone knows about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [basic memory management rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) again.

You didn't create the `NSURLRequest` using a method containing the words  “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”, so you don't own it, so you shouldn't release it.

Also, you are not "calling an asynchronous function". When you call `[webView loadRequest:]`, the method call happens immediately and synchronously. That method starts some asynchronous work behind the scenes, which completes later on -- but that doesn't affect the way that you call the method in the first place, or the memory management for its arguments.

Comment: At first, thanks for the explanation...but when i get the retainCount of the request, it returns 1, same with when you alloc,int. how do you explain that?

Comment: [retainCount is useless](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/12/18/retaincount-is-useless/).